# Calling a PHP file from AJAX

Tags: magento

I'm trying to develop a small site using Magento, in which I'm trying to display a dynamic content based on the user selection from the drop down box.

So far I've done a JavaScript and used AJAX for XMLHTTP request for the PHP file, its based on the code provided by w3schools example as follows

```
function loadLocations(value){
var xmlhttp;
if (value==0)
{
  document.getElementById("locationList").innerHTML="";
  return;
}
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
  {
    document.getElementById("locationList").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;

  }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","getLocations.php?countryID="+value,true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

}

and the getLocations.php is placed in the path

> app/code/local/company/module/Block/

and my doubt is how to point the getLocations.php file in the particular location.

Any help, Thanks All.

Comment: Good effort in teaching yourself AJAX. However you should save yourself the trouble and just use [Ajax.Updater](http://api.prototypejs.org/ajax/Ajax/Updater/)

Comment: Thanks for your valuable appreciation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) You must create controller.
    companyName/yuormodule/controllers/AjaxController.php
2) In AjaxController.php create action, for example indexAction(). See code section

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->renderLayout();    
}
```

3) Then add to yourlayout.xml (example: app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/yourlayout.xml) next code

```
    <yourmodule_ajax_index>
        <block type="yourmodule/getlocations" name="root" template="path/file.phtml">
        </block>
    </yourmodule_ajax_index>
```

4) Then you must update layout in your confix.xml.

> ```
> <layout>
>     <updates>
>         <yourmodule>
>             <file>yourlayout.xml</file>
>         </yourmodule>
>     </updates>
> </layout>
> ```

5) After this instance of your getLocation class will be available in file.phtml.

6)  And last, just need to change this code `xmlhttp.open("GET","getLocations.php?countryID="+value,true);` to `xmlhttp.open("GET","yourmodule/ajax/index/countryID/"+value,true);`

Answer (score 1):

You should make a controller class to handle your functionality. So for example: *app/code/local/company/module/controllers/AjaxController.php*. You can read online about controllers (they are a core part of magento). Then you would call most likely something like `http://mywebsite.dom/module/ajax/getlocations/countryID/34/`.

As far as I know this would be the best method.

P.S. If you're new to Magento, I would suggest this series to learn a bit: http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-1-introduction-to-magento.